# What is a market basket problem?

Tags: dataset, data-mining

Can somebody tell me or give a reference about the "Market Basket Problem" in data  mining. What is this problem about? Any scientific reference with application will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is [Association rule learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning).

Comment: If the answer of RomaH is not the one you are looking for, please state why. Otherwise I suggest to accept it ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to the Market Basket Problem that I am thinking of…  It is simple the question of, "What is the probability that product C is in the basket if person A has placed product B in the basket?"

It can be as simple as a series of Chi studies and correlations.  I prefer to stick to Occam's Razor and keep my solutions simple until I find a problem or need that requires more complex solutions.

Now that I am no longer in school and don't have good access to academia databases I just did a quick Google of that phrase "Market Basket Problem" and the first few results are some academic article on the subject for free.

I liked this article and found it useful, [PDF from Penn State](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.118.6071&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
I hope this helps you.